# Creating a honeypot for nodejs / hapi.js

Tags: node.js, security, hapi.js, honeypot

I have a hapijs application and checking some logs I have found some entries for automated site scanners and hits to entries to /admin.php and similar.

I found this great article [How to Block Automated Scanners from Scanning your Site](http://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/block-automated-scanners/) and I thought it was great.

I am looking for guidance on what the best strategy would be to create honey pots for a hapijs / nodejs app to identify suspicious requests, log them, and possibly ban the IPs temporarily.

Do you have any general or specific (to node and hapi) recommendations on how to implement this?

My thoughts include:

- Create the honeypot route with a non-obvious name
- Add a robots.txt to disallow search engines on that route
- Create the content of the route (see the article and discussions for some of the recommendations)
- Write to a special log or tag the log entries for easy tracking and later analysis
- Possibly create some logic that if traffic from this IP address receives more traffic than certain threshold (5 times of honeypot route access will ban the IP for X hours or permanently)

A few questions I have:

- How can you ban an IP address using hapi.js?
- Are there any other recommendations to identify automated scanners?
- Do you have specific suggestions for implementing a honeypot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let me start with saying that this Idea sounds really cool but I'm not if it is much practical.

First the chances of blocking legit bots/users is small but still exisits.
Even if you ignore true mistakes the option for abuse and denial of service is quite big. Once I know your blocking users who enter this route I can try cause legit users touch it (with an iframe / img / redirect) and cause them to be banned from the site.

Than it's effectiveness is small. sure your going to stop all automated bots that scan your sites (I'm sure the first thing they do is check the Disallow info and this is the first thing you do in a pentest). But only unsophisticated attacks are going to be blocked cause anyone actively targeting you will blacklist the endpoint and get a different IP.

So I'm not saying you shouldn't do it but I am saying you should think to see if the pros outwaite the cons here.

How to actually get it done is actually quite simple. And it seem like your looking for a very unique case of `rate limiting` I wouldn't do it directly in your hapi app since you want the ban to be shared between instances and you probably want them to be persistent across restarts (You can do it from your app but it's too much logic for something that is already solved).

The article you mentioned actually suggests using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) which is a great solution for rate limiting. you'll need to make sure your app logs to  afile it can read and write a `filter` and `jail` conf specifically for your app but it should work with hapi with no issues.

Specifically for hapi I maintain an npm module for rate limiting called [ralphi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ralphi) it has a hapi plugin but unless you need a proper rate limiting (which you should have for logins, sessions and other tokens) fail2ban might be a better option in this case.

In general Honey pots are not hard to implement but as with any secuiry related solution you should consider who is your potential attacker and what are you trying to protect.

Also in general Honey pots are mostly used to notify about an existing breach or an imminent breach. Though they can be used to also trigger a lockdown your main take from them is to get visibility once a breach happend but before the attacker had to much time to abuse the system (You don't want to discover the breach two months later when your site has been defaced and all valuable data was already taken)

A few ideas for honey pots can be -

- Have an 'admin' user with relatively average password (random 8 chars) but no privileges at all when this user successfully loges in notify the real admin.

  Notice that your not locking the attacker on first attempt to login even if you know he is doing something wrong (he will get a different ip and use another account). But if he actually managed to loggin, maybe there's an error in your login logic ? maybe password reset is broken ? maybe rate limiting isn't working ? So much more info to follow through.

  now that you know you have a semi competent attacker maybe try and see what is he trying to do, maybe you'll know who he is or what his end goal is (Highly valuable since he probably going to try again).
- Find sensitive places you don't want users to play with and plant some [canary tokens](https://canarytokens.org/generate) in. This can be just a file that sites with all your other uploads on the system, It can be an AWS creds on your dev machine, it can be a link that goes from your admin panel that says "technical documentation" the idea is that regular users should not care or have any access to this files but attackers will find them too tempting to ignore. the moment they touch one you know this area has been compromised and you need to start blocking and investigating

Just remember before implementing any security in try to think who you expect is going to attack you honey pots are probably one of the last security mesaures you should consider and there are a lot more common and basic security issues that need to be addressed first (There are endless amount of lists about [node.js security](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/) best practices and [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) defacto standard for general web apps security)